# Indentation Error: expected an indented block

Tags: python, csv

I keep getting this error telling me to indent my block but I don't see where I would need to do that, especially if I'm running two try clause. I am trying to allow my second try clause to print to a log like the first one. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!usr/bin/python


from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file


try:
f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
    for line in f:

        try: 
            for row in f: 

                if solution_id != row[2]:
                    print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
        except ValueError: 
            logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
                else:
                    print row







finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if `if solution_id != row[2]:` is True? You seem to be missing a line.

Comment: get an IDE and it'll tell you

Comment: If the solution_id which is a command arg, is not equal to the solution id, which is in a csv file, then an error will kick out and crate a log file for it.

Comment: You give us 83 lines of code and don't mention which line has the problem. Python tells you exactly which line has the indentation problem and its very easy to see that its because you have an `if` statement without a body directly above it.

Answer (score 0):

What is

```
else:
  print row
```

connected to?  It should be indented from something that needs an else, but it's in column 1...

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Its part of a `try/except/else` block, so not a problem.

Comment: I fixed the 'else' problem but I'm now getting an invalid syntax with the carat on the last letter on the 'else'

Answer (score 0):

In the second try statement. you have and if statement with no action

```
    for row in f: 
        try:    
            if solution_id != row[2]:
        except ValueError: 
            logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again')
```

needs be have something like

```
    for row in f: 
        try:    
            if solution_id != row[2]:
                print "row error"
        except ValueError: 
            logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again')
```

The if statement is trying to use the except as the action after the conditinal.

EDIT::
I don't have cvs to test with. but i get no other errors from this code:

```
#!usr/bin/python


from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file


try:
    f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
    for line in f:

        try: 
            for row in f: 

                if solution_id != row[2]:
                    print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
        except ValueError: 
            logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
        else:
            print row







finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"
```

Comment: Now in the current code you need to indent after the first try: f=cvs.read and move the else back to be in line with the second try; and except: